# How to read CSV file data from middle of csv file using CsvHelper package in c#

Tags: csvhelper

I have a csv file which starts from row 15(with column headers) and first 14 line of data which is not needed. How can i read it and map with Model class?

I tried using CsvHelper package in c# but no luck to read from row 15. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 1) Just to clarify, do you mean that the **headers** start on line 15,and the first 14 lines are to be ignored, or that the headers are on line 1 as usual and the data starts on the 15th line after the headers? 2) You wrote, *I tried using CsvHelper package in c# but no luck to read from row 15. * -- then might you please [edit] your question to and share a [mcve] with CSV file + code showing what you tried that did not work?  That would help clarify your problem and also prevent us from trying solutions you already know won't work.  See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ShouldSkipRecord` in `CsvConfiguration` to skip the first 14 rows.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Some Text");
    }
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("Id,Name");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("1,First");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("2,Second");   
    var input = stringBuilder.ToString();
    
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        ShouldSkipRecord = args => args.Row.Context.Parser.RawRow < 15
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader(input))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```